# Como é a logica para fazer a impressão dos números em ordem crescente em C

Tags: c, array

criei um código que pega um determinado de números estabelecido pelo usuário, e faz a separação de pares e impares, até ai consegui fazer, o meu problema é colocar os números em ordem crescente para que o código ficasse mais bonito visualmente na hora da impressão, imprimindo em ordem tanto os pares quanto os impares.
segue o código como esta atualmente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

  int quantVetor = 0,vetPar[100],vetImpar[100],quantPar = 0,quantImpar = 0,posicao[100],i;

  printf("Digite o tamanho do vetor que deseja\n");
  scanf("%d",&quantVetor);
  //
  printf("Atribua os valores ao vetor\n");
  for (i = 0; i < quantVetor ; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &posicao[i]);

  if(posicao[i] % 2 == 0){
      vetPar[quantPar]=posicao[i];
      quantPar++;
} else{
      vetImpar[quantImpar]=posicao[i];
      quantImpar++;
} // fim else
  } // fim for

  printf("\n\n");

  for (i = 0; i < quantPar; i++) {
   printf("par %d\n\n",vetPar[i] );
  } // fim for
  for (int i = 0; i < quantImpar; i++) {
    printf("impar %d\n\n",vetImpar[i] );
  } // fim for
  return 0;
}
```

Como eu gostaria que ficasse a saída:
Pares : 2,4,6
Impares: 1,3,5
e assim em diante.(não precisa ser lado a lado mas caso tenha como fazer gostaria de saber como é).

Comment: Pesquise por algoritmos de ordenação. Existe um farto material na internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seria necessário outra função para ordenar os valores. Vou deixar um exemplo simples:

```
for (int indice = 0; indice < quantPar; indice++) //Loop para percorrer o vetor
{
        for (int indice2 = 0; indice2 < quantPar; indice2++) //Loop para comparar
        {
            if (vetPar[indice2] > vetPar[indice]) //Comparando os elementos
            {
                int tmp = vetPar[indice]; // Usando uma variável temporária para armazenar o valor
                // Trocando os valores
                vetPar[indice] = vetPar[indice2]; 
                vetPar[indice2] = tmp;
            }  
        }
    }
```

Testei nesse site: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Essa implementação é conhecida como Bubble Sort(Método Bolha), mas existem outros. Por exemplo: Inserting Sorte, Heap Sort, Selection sort e Quick sort.
[Link para uma lista mais completinha](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Answer (score -1):

Para ordenar o `array` você pode utilizar o `qsort()` mais ou menos da maneira exemplificada.
Para alterar a ordem, `desc` ou `asc` é só trocar a ordem da comparação de `a - b` para `b - a`

```
int compareInt(const void *a, const void *b) {
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main() {
   /** le valores.. **/

   qsort(pares, tam_array_pares, sizeof(int), compareInt);
   qsort(impares, tam_array_impares, sizeof(int), compareInt);

   /** printa valores **/
}
```

Mais detalhes aqui: [qsort()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm)